# Appropriate extension for this use case

Tags: swift, swiftui

Originally I was looking to make an extension on `Text` for example:

```swift
extension Text {
    var headerText: Text {
       self
        .bold()
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .padding() //<-- Doesn't work 
    }
 }
```

and it all worked except for padding

So I had the bright idea of writing an extension on `View` instead but then the `.bold()` wouldn't work..

Looking for a more *swifty* way of doing this. Thanks

Comment: You'd have to do `var headerText: some View` then.

Comment: `.bold()` will not work on that

Comment: It will, as long as you don't do `extension View`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, this seems like the perfect case for a custom view modifier...

```
struct HeaderText: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .bold()
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

...which you could then use like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is a header")
            .modifier(HeaderText())
    }
}
```

You could also put the modifier inside a view extension to make it cleaner, like so:

```
extension View {
    func headerText() -> ModifiedContent<Self, HeaderText> {
        return modifier(HeaderText())
    }
}
```

That would enable you to use it like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            Text("This is a header")
                .headerText()
        }
}
```

Comment: although interestingly enough, `.bold()` does not work on the first code snippet of your answer

Comment: Ah yeah, because .bold() only works for Text views. You could try .font(Font.body.bold()), or, if you need to be able to set varying text sizes, add "var size: CGFloat" to the ViewModifier struct and change it to ".font(Font.system(size: size).bold())"